# standard representation for symmetric groups motivation

Tags: representation-theory

I was wondering what the motivation for the standard representation of a symmetric group is? For example, for $S_n$, why do you want to consider the one dim. subspace of the sum of the basis vectors in the regular representation (vector of all 1's), and it's complement? How do you know the complement (the n-1 dim. subspace) is irreducible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried showing it is irreducible? It is not a difficult exercise.

Comment: There's an inner product for representations. A representation is irreducible iff its dot product with itself is one.

Answer (score 1):

The permution representation of $S_n$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is very natural. Now it is not irreducible. It is pretty obvious that it has a $1$-dimensional trivial representation inside. Morevoer, it has a unique complement: this makes that complement quite a natural object! That complement is the standard representation.

Comment: I don't understand why the 1 dim representation is trivial; is it because it has all 1's in it and 1 is the identity, or is it because any permutation of the components of the vector (1,1,...,1) (all 1's) gives the same vector?

Comment: Also, I'm quite new to representation theory, so I don't know how to show the n-1 dim subspace is irreducible